# GA shows zero visitors in my blog but real time is ok

Tags: google-analytics, blogspot

[My blog](https://stayinpoland.blogspot.com) started working already from May, 2016.
But until today I'm able to see just real time visitors.
There abot defined any filters.
Can someone of experts in GA debug or\and tell me what is the problem?

Here is my analitics code:

```
<!-- Google Analytics -->
    <script>
        (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
        (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
        m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
        })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

        ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxxxx-1', 'auto');
        ga('set', 'forceSSL', true);
        ga('require', 'displayfeatures');
        ga('require', 'linkid', 'linkid.js');
        ga('send', 'pageview');
    </script>
    <!-- End Google Analytics -->
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the issue?

Comment: Have you checked your date ranges?

Comment: 1. Igneel64, Problem is that I'm not able to see users sessions on my blog. I just can see Real-Time visitors.
2. sdhaus, Yes, I checked date ranges, there are zeroes for whole the year.

Comment: You can check screenshots for better understanding:  

[Real Time](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxkUwE5KSjcESllkWEJINTlRRWM)

[Overview](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxkUwE5KSjcEWk1vY1RpUEJIaXM)

Answer (score 1):

Your screenshot says your are using a filtered view (your posts says "there abot defined any filters" which seems to be a typo and I am not sure what it means). What filters do you use ?

The bigger issue might be that your code is for web tracking, but your screenshot show reports for app tracking (telltale sign is e.g. that you have a menu item for "app versions"). Since this records screen views, but not pageviews, the reports might very well remain empty when you sent pageviews with javascript.

I have no idea why this would have worked before, but you should try switching to a web view.

Comment: Yes, there was a typo, it should be read as "there are not defined any filters". Screenshots were made before I removed filters. Filters were just to exclude my IPs.

Re switching to "web view". Can you please tell me how to do this? In Google Analitics interface?

Comment: Should I try to replace in code with ga('send', 'screenview'); ?

Comment: You would need to create a new property (which also means you would loose existing data and would have to start new with a new tracking id). I suspect there is more to your use case then is evident from your post, because it seems very strange that this should have worked in the past.

Comment: I have a blogger too, try this  replace these lines  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXX-1', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

  </script>

Comment: Coupon rabais, thanks. I did and will check in few days.